# What slideshow script is 'tumblr.com' using?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

The url is like below.
http://www.tumblr.com/

On the main page, you can see 3 images keep rotating, which I first thought was a swf, actually is not. They are the images each in `<li>` tag.

Is there any script out there that can do this? If then, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the Tumblr but you can use [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) to create a lot of effects if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the source they import the file prototype_and_effects.js so they are most likely using the [Prototype Framework](http://www.prototypejs.org/) (a popular alternative to jQuery) and [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/) for the rotating banner effect, which is also included in that file.

Check out their [effects demo page](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/combination-effects-demo/) for examples and documentation.